# I need to detect forms in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi my problem is that i have to implement a logic that detect if for example the "X" makes a 2x2 square. In this code you have to insert 4 times a string of 4 digits in an ArrayList in which it will be a "X" if its a a "plastic cube" ("plastic cube" helps to visualize that the output is a "plastic form") or a "." if its not.

So if the input is:

..XX

..XX

....

....

I have to detect that is a cube 2X2 and return for example "Its a cube".

I would appreciate if you could help me since I am stuck.

```
  public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException { {
ArrayList <String> cajita=new <String> ArrayList();
Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the first 4-digit line."
        + " \nIt should contain 'x' if it is a piece of plastic."
        + " \nY '.' in other case."
        + " \n Max 4 chars!");

for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
cajita.add(entrada.nextLine());
    }
for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    System.out.println();
    for(int f=0;f<4;f++) {
        System.out.print(cajita.get(i).charAt(f));
    }
  }

}
```

}

Comment: A "[**digit**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/digit)" is *"any of the Arabic numerals 1 to 9 and usually the symbol 0"*, so e.g. an `x` is not valid if you're asking for "digits". I think you meant "[**character**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_(computing))", which includes letters, digits, symbols, etc.

Comment: A "[**cube**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube)" is a 3D object. The input is only 2D, so you meant "[**square**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square)", same as you called it in the first sentence.

Comment: Yes you are correct, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

- Verify that a user-entered line is exactly 4 long and consists of only `.` and `X`, otherwise ask user to re-enter a valid line.
- Once you have 4 valid lines, count the number of X's. If not 4, then it's not a square.
- Find the first X, then:

  - Check that next position in the line is also an X.
  - Check that line below has X in same position.
  - Check that line below has X in next position.
- If any of those checks fail, then it's not a square.
- Otherwise it's a square.

Have fun coding that.